# Symfony Flash Message by external link

Tags: symfony, symfony4, flash-message

On symfony 4.1

if I copy/paste http://mysite/sdff453212f/newPassword/{code} in my browser it shows a Flash Message as expected.

but if I send this url by mail (or copy in word document...) and I Click the link it doesn't show any flash message ( but if intercept_redirects: true, it's work...)

Do you have any ideas?

my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/newPassword/{code}", name="newPassword")
 */
 public function newPassword(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $encoder, $code)
{
    //....
    $this->addFlash('error', 'Le code n\'existe pas ou n\'est plus valable');
    return $this->redirectToRoute('security_forgot_Password');
}


/**
 * @Route("forgotPassword", name="security_forgot_Password")
 */
public function forgotPassword(Request $request, UtilityManager $utility, MailManager $mailManager)
{

    $form = $this->createForm(ForgotPasswordType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
         //.....
    }
    return $this->render('security/forgotPassword.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Comment: route path on forgotPassword method should start with / as well

Comment: thanks but no change...

Comment: on what page do you land when clicking it from your mail?

Comment: For anyone else seeing this, I found that the flash message would display okay by this method in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari. I'm still trying to figure out whether this is some weird Safari security measure or maybe caused by some extension I have enabled...